# % change between two dataframes

Tags: pandas

Trying to divide the df2 by df1 to get the % change between each date

df1

```
 Index Dates            SPX   Oil
 30    11/01/2001       1326  25
 35    09/11/2011       1350  30
```

df2

```
 Index Dates            SPX   Oil
 30    16/01/2001       1450  22
 35    16/11/2011       1451  23
```

So should be 1450 SPX in 2nd df / 1326 SPX in 1st df to give the %

```
df = df2.set_index('Dates').div(df1.set_index('Date')).sub(1).mul(100).reset_index()
```

the above code gives me this error

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
>   index

Comment: Can you please post actual machine readable code that reproduced the DFs in question?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but you're missing some holes in your logic & request - what _dates_ are you trying to measure, and if there is a date to measure is there a `primary` key between both tables that lets you compare both dataframes? if both dataframes are of exactly equal length are you trying to measure the change of values in index 0 for both dataframes? have a think about it and re-frame your question. Not clear what your trying to do.

Comment: So the dates and index are less relevant here. It is the prices columns of spx and oil, which i need the % change of

Comment: key is that the dates are different in this case so cannto do df2/df1 -1

Comment: What if df1 row and df2 is ten?